# Prove that if two circles touch one another, then these chords, drawn from the tangency point, are proportional.

Tags: geometry, circles

Prove that if two circles touch one another, then chords of the internal circle, drawn from the tangency point, are proportional to the chords of the outer circle that you get when you extend the chords of the internal circle.

I hope I've made the question clear.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what "inner circle" and "outer circle" mean?  Do you mean a pair of circles with one inside the other and one common point of intersection between them?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Actually, I think the question can be generally the same whether one is inside the other or not, just take any collinear chords from each circle that pass through the tangent point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ratio of the chords is equal to the ratio of the diameters.

(Thus, the ratio depends only on the diameters, not the specific position of the chords.)

Another proof without words, incorporating @abiessu's observation that the circles need not be *internally* tangent.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Proof without words:

[image: Image description]

where $O$ is the center of the outer circle, $I$ is the center of the inner circle, and $A$ is their point of tangency.

Comment: How can I upload an image to my answer like you've just done?

Comment: @mathh: When you accumulate 100 reputation points, you'll get to use an "Add Image" button.